# Angular, Expressjs and Lusca csrf protection

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, csrf

I am investigating csrf protection with my Angularjs and Expressjs (4.x) app.

I am currently trying to get Lusca (https://www.npmjs.org/package/lusca) to work having not been successful with the standard csrf package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/csrf).

I have included lusca like so:

```
var lusca = require('lusca');
app.use(lusca.csrf());
```

and in my Angularjs app I have this in my main app.js file:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $cookies, user) {

  $http.defaults.headers.post['x-csrf-token'] = $cookies._csrf;

});
```

however, I'm always getting a 403 error when I try to POST anything to the node server. Can anyone help or even show me the way with the standard csrf package?

Answer (score 0):

you should read

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

at the bottom where they talk about XSRF protection

this would be a configuration example to set both the header and the cookie

```
AP.config(['$httpProvider', function($$httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName="xsrf header name";
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName="xsrf cookie name";

}]);
```

Comment: Saw that a long time ago - doesn't really help me though - there are no code examples or anything!

Comment: just edited my response with a small configuration peace, you can use, that shuold work